# Login in java web-app and show jsp template

Tags: java, jsp, authentication

My problem is that I have 2 jsp files in my project: `login.jsp` and `adminpanel.jsp`.

My aim is to show the user the `login.jsp` template and let him log in via a form inside it.

After login, I want my app to show `adminpanel.jsp` and this is my problem that I can still access it by just writing url .../adminpanel.jsp.

How can I disable this option? It just makes no sense to login if you can reach `adminpanel.jsp` so easily.

Comment: Announcing thanks should never be part of a good question: no chit-chat (read [help→tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)).

Comment: Where are you checking the user credentials? In a LoginServlet?

Comment: yes, I check it in LoginServlet.processRequest();

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is set a session variable when user logs in via login.jsp ie only if both username and password is correct .

after that on all other pages ( including adminpanel.jsp ) check if the session variable exist. If yes allow user to view the page , else redirect to login page.

Also check http_redirect or url rewritting by which you can mask original url.

Check links below for more info

http://www.jsptut.com/sessions.jsp

http://www.javatpoint.com/url-rewriting-in-session-tracking

Comment: Sounds clever. I will check this out in a while, at this point I tried to use doFilter() simillar way (with Attribute made in LoginServlet), but your version should be easier and cleaner. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, your authentication should be handled by a servlet (essentially your controller class). Second all views that should not be directly accessed like in your case ought to be placed inside your WEB-INF folder, forcing your application to call the appropriate controller class. It is here where you force redirects or forwards based on your business logic and session /cookie management.